# Simple SDL + openGL code for displaying images in 2D alone, no 3D involved

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl

I'm inexperienced in 2D, and about a week ago started messing with SDL. Built some simple structures to have images, which would be on layers, so I could have my own drawing order, so sprites would be drawn after background, etc, and then did a little "sprite engine".
I got a Megaman sprite walking left and right just like I wanted it, above a simple 900x900ish background image.

Thing is, CPU almost reached 20% on my i5... so I thought of using the graphic card to do the drawing! Delved abit into OpenGL and today, finally managed to get gl3w working!

So now I'm looking for a simple way to display my sprites/images, on the window, through use of OpenGL. I've tried all sorts of code I ran across, but I can't get anything displaying, despite that I've done error checks basically everywhere, and everything seems to check out to be right!

**TL:DR; I was looking for some simple working code, using SDL, on how to draw 2D images (which, if it doesn't work, for sure I've got something wrong).**

Additional question: I found out about the gamedev stackexchange: should I/can I post duplicates here and there? This question might fit both? (I did it just this once)

Comment: Your problem is too broad - do you have a window? An OpenGL context? Did you set up the viewport and view matrix correctly? Narrow your problem down to something we can work on.

Comment: I have nothing set up: want a piece of code, including openGL initialization, up to the point I get a image displaying on my window. Only thing that's done, is the creating of a window by SDL, using the SDL_OPENGL, and getting OpenGL extensions available through gl3winit().

Comment: why are you using opengl and sdl if you're not doing 3d, sdl is perfectly able to handle 2d by itself and as for the 20% on an i5, make sure you are regulating your fps properly.

Comment: I am regulating the framerate well, am running at 60FPS per second. Using /or trying to/ use openGL because like I said, rendering just the background with 1 moving sprite, already topped 20%